# Incorrect syntax for dynamic SQL statement

Tags: asp.net

```
private ResponseDTO SyncPODetails(PODTO po)
    {
        string query = "";
        try
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("insert into " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbUser"] + ".PODetail(WHSEID, POKEY, POLINENUMBER, STORERKEY, SKU, SKUDESCRIPTION, QTYORDERED, QTYADJUSTED, QTYRECEIVED, PACKKEY, UNITPRICE, UOM, EFFECTIVEDATE, FORTE_FLAG, ITEM_NUMBER, SKU_WGT, SKU_CUBE, SKU_HGT, UNIT_COST, UNIT_SHIP, SUSR1, SUSR2, QTYREJECTED, STATUS, QCAUTOADJUST, QCREQUIRED, ADDDATE, ADDWHO, EDITDATE, EDITWHO, ITEMPRICEREF, POPLANID, LOADPLANQTY, ORDERKEY, ORDERLINENUMBER, ASSIGNEDQTY, SUPPLIERRECEIVEDQTY, SUPPLIERRECEIPTDATE, QTYPOPULATED, ORDEREDQTY)" + " values('LMRWHS1','{0}','{1}','KGL','{2}','{3}',{4},0.00,0.00,'{5}',{6},'{7}','{8}','I',0,{9},{10},0.00,{11},0.00,'{12}','{13}',0.00,0,0,0,'{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}','{19}',0.00,'{20}','{21}',0.00,0.00,'{22}',0.00,0.00)");

            foreach (var pd in po.POdetails)
            {
               //query = query + "select max(SERIALKEY) SERIALKEY from " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbUser"] + ".PODetail";
                query = string.Format(query,
                   sb.Append(po.POKey),
                    sb.Append(pd.POLineNumber),
                    sb.Append(pd.NSN),
                    sb.Append(pd.NSNDescription),
                    sb.Append(pd.OpenQuantity),//pd.PalletQuantities.Sum(x => x.PalletQuantity),
                    sb.Append("STD"),
                    sb.Append(pd.UnitPrice),
                    sb.Append(pd.UOM),
                    sb.Append(po.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")),
                    sb.Append(pd.STDGROSSWGT),
                    sb.Append("0"),
                    sb.Append(pd.UnitPrice),
                    sb.Append(pd.AgreementRefNo),
                    sb.Append("DRY"),
                    sb.Append(po.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")),
                    sb.Append(pd.CreatedByName),
                    sb.Append(po.UpdatedDate.Year < 1990 ? null : po.UpdatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")),
                    sb.Append(pd.UpdatedByName),
                    sb.Append(pd.ITEMPRICEREF),
                    sb.Append(po.PlanNo),
                    sb.Append(pd.WMSOrderKey),
                    sb.Append(pd.CustomerOrderLineNo),
                    sb.Append(po.VendorDeliveryDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
                    );

            }
            var result = ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionStringCPRD, sb.ToString());
            return new ResponseDTO { Status = true, Message = "PO  Synced sucessfully", SingleResponse = po.Id };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RevereseSync(po);
            LogHelper.LogError("Sync PO Details" + query, ex);
            return new ResponseDTO { Status = false, Message = "PO  not synced sucessfully", SingleResponse = po.Id };
        }
    }
```

Comment: incorrect syntax near '4'  is thow to resolve this issue

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question in order to **describe the problem** and **formulate an actual question**. Don't just dump a huge amount of code for us to untangle. It will also help to **include the generated output**, which from the looks of it, is missing whitespace in various places.

Comment: **Redo it using SQL parameters.** It will be safer against SQL injection attacks, apostrophes, and typos. Do not use AddWithValue because that leaves it open to run-time oopsies.

Comment: please write some example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to bulk insert in your database.

In that case, you use `sb` to accumulate (`sb.AppendFormat`) your individual queries (the thing you initialize your `sb` with now), and then send your parameters as strings to the Format call (which is what you're never supposed to do).

Comment: Could you please write once i have not understand

Comment: Actually your understand correctly.Please write some code.